# Django save string to date field

Tags: django, datefield

In my Django application I have a DateField (format 'YYYY-MM-DD'). When I try to save the string '2011-11-01' I get no error but my fields gets the NULL value.

I tried to do that with strptime function from datetime and time libraries but with the same issue. Basically it all happens in a form

I have

```
    if form.valid():
        form.cleaned_data['date'] = year + '-' + month + '-' day
        form.save()
```

Comment: Please show some real code. What fields are in the form? Where are year, month and day coming from?

Answer (score 2):

part of the form validation inclues cleaning the data. the `cleaned_data` dict contains python objects, not the (string) post data.

so `form.cleaned_data['data']` needs to be a `datetime` object (or you need to edit the form or post data before cleaning)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the model object that accepts the date object and confirm that you did not set it to always be null ... Actually I think the misnomer is there, not in the view or save method but in the model object that should take a date object. Maybe you should consider posting your model code here so we see.

Comment: The problem was that I was writing data in form.cleaned_data and it seems that it's not correct. The correct way to do this is to make f = form.save(commit=False) then f.date = datetime(year,month,day) then f.save() form.save_m2m()...Thank you all and hope this is helpful for you too.

Comment: I will make some research to see why the way I was doing is not correct